# WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Error is as shown below. The problem is, occurring as below, this XmlWebApplicationContext need not occur, since it's injecting the bean again. How to avoid it?

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh

INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 08 12:40:44 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PersistenceManagerContext.xml]
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/ServiceApiContext.xml]
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/RuleEngineContext.xml]
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/CacheContext.xml]
Sep 08, 2015 12:40:45 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl] for bean with name 'MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PersistenceManagerContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:974)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
    ... 19 more

Sep 08, 2015 12:40:45 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl] for bean with name 'MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PersistenceManagerContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:974)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
    ... 19 more

Sep 08, 2015 12:40:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl] for bean with name 'MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PersistenceManagerContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:974)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
    ... 19 more
```

Web.xml

```
<!-- USing the dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- The pattern is /* -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Looking for beans in *Context.xml files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/*Context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Dispatcher-Servlet.xml

```
<!-- <import resource="/WEB-INF/context/*Context.xml"></import> -->

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then we have a bunch of context xmls available in the folder "CONTEXT".

Pom: [image: This is my pom]

PersistenceManager has that class:

```
[![PersistenceManager is in the war][2]][2]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was my stupidity, but a stupidity that was not easy to identify :).

Problem:

1. My code is compiled on Jdk 1.8.
2. My eclipse, had JDK 1.8 as the compiler.
3. My tomcat in eclipse was using Java 1.7 for its container, hence it was not able to understand the .class files which were compiled using 1.8.
4. To avoid the problem, ensure in your eclipse, double click on your server -> Open Launch configuration -> Classpath -> JRE System Library -> Give the JDK/JRE of the compiled version of java class, in my case, it had to be JDK 1.8

   5. Post this, clean the server, build and redeploy, start the tomcat.

If you are deploying manually into your server, ensure your JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME points to the correct JDK which you used to compile the project and build the war.

If you do not like to change JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, you can always change the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME in catalina.bat(for tomcat server) and that'll enable your life to be easy!

Answer (score 2):

The important part is this:

```
Cannot find class [com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl] for bean with name 'MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PersistenceManagerContext.xml];
```

due to:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakuten.points.persistence.manager.MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl
```

According to this log, Spring could not find your `MemberPointSummaryDAOImpl` class.

Comment: Hey, I know that error is turning up, but that's not the issue! 

It's in my pom. I Will update the pom and the screenshot having the class. That's not the issue. 

The issue is with this:
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

Comment: Can you verify that this jar (with this class in it) is available under your WEB-INF/lib folder in the Tomcat working directory?

Comment: The Jar does exist with the class in the lib folder. I am not able to upload the screenshot for some reason.

But yes, ofcourse, it does exist.

The problem I see is, it's not able to cancel refresh and hence the bean is getting injected again and there it throws an error.

Comment: @Pavanraotk : I am facing the same issue.Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RockingDev: Check my answer above, mine was because the tomcat in my eclipse was on JDK 1.7, hence the problem. Could it be similar to you?

Comment: @Pavanraodk Its not because that.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't really believe, but **maven clean** helped me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using j-hipster and I had to do `./mvnw clean` to overcome this warning.

Answer (score 0):

1. To closed ideas,
2. To remove all folder and file C:/Users/UserName/.m2/org/*,
3. Open ideas and update Maven project,(right click on project -> maven->update maven project)
4. After that update the project.