# Invalid bean definition with name 'configServicePropertySource'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, spring-config

I have defined `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator` bean like following

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator configServicePropertySource(
        ConfigClientProperties configClientProperties) {
    ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator sourceLocator = new ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator(
            configClientProperties);
    sourceLocator.setRestTemplate(clientOnlyRestTemplate());
    return sourceLocator;
}
```

but i get the following exception (This is how it is printed in docker) although my bean is marked as `@Primary`

```
WARN 1 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'configServicePropertySource' defined in de.ig.client.security.configuration.ConfigClientSecurityConfiguration: 
Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; 
dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=configClientSecurityConfiguration; 
factoryMethodName=configServicePropertySource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); 
defined in de.ig.client.security.configuration.ConfigClientSecurityConfiguration] for bean 'configServicePropertySource': 
There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; 
autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=configServiceBootstrapConfiguration; 
factoryMethodName=configServicePropertySource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); 
defined in org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration] bound.
```

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451718/warning-exception-encountered-during-context-initialization-cancelling-refres)

Comment: @buræquete the link mention class load issue. This one is bean override issue. Worse part is even with Primary annotation its throws exception. Weird.

Comment: Looks weird.. but  you can add @Order(-1) and remove @Primary...

Comment: @JonathanJohx After putting order same exception.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by setting

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to **true**

New from boot version 2.1